# Is any GIS processing in Python bound to be single threaded due to the GIL?

Tags: python, gdal, ogr

I'm processing a really complex geometry using Python and `ogr`, which is taking forever to compute.

Looking at the CPU usage, I've noticed that it never exceeds 100% (more than 100% signals that the process is using more than one CPU core).

I'm wondering if this is due to Python Global Interpreter Locker, which makes Python single threaded.
However, `ogr` and `gdal` are written in C++.

So, my doubt is: given that the `ogr` and `gdal` Python libraries are just a wrapper for C++ `ogr` and `gdal`, is any processing carried out using these libraries bound to be single threaded, due to the libraries being called by Python?

Comment: Is it really one single geometry object (e.g. one line or polygon) that you want to have processed on multiple cores/threads?

Comment: It's a layer with 12 really complex muli polygons, representing land cover and usage

Comment: In that case I am not aware of any GIS software or toolkit that will process them very efficiently. If you can and if it fits your analysis, the common way to handle those is to split them up into e. g. a smaller grid of many small polygons, spatially index them and enjoy fast operations.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is the way to go, process one type of coverage at a time and send every process to be handled by a different core. However, I was just curious about how GIS libraries work when called inside a Python script